# Implementing a "method" for parallel processing, for fetching and dispatching data

Tags: python, multithreading, queue

Here is what I am trying to do, (trying to do it in python3.x)

1. Stream text data from a infinite source (has a api to do so)each text has a user id
2. Extract few features from this text.
3. Fetch appropriate data from another database, using the extracted data as search query
4. Reply to the original user id with the currently fetched data.

Example: I need to fetch around  100 (id,data) pairs and extract data from  each one of them, now out of these 100 its likely only  20 pairs are such which need to be replied to , so for these 20 i will need to fetch data from a different database with the "search query" and reply to  these 20 pairs in the form like (id,newdata)

What I have now ?

For now I am able to everything, but nothing is in parallel processing,ie my code does everything one-after the other. Which is just not the right way to do it.

What I need help in ?

I want to implement some kind of Multi threaded queue. I  am looking for help ,  on how to implement something like this
Any help /nudge in the right direction would be very helpful

Thank you

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: learn multithreading ?